# Converting CanvasRenderer to WebGLRenderer

Tags: javascript, three.js

I would like to take the example here:
https://threejs.org/examples/?q=canvas#canvas_particles_waves

And use it with the WebGLRenderer, by changing:

`renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();`

to

`renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();`

So that I can combine this effect with another that is already using WebGL.

However, doing so results in errors with the particles being rendered, like so:

`three.js:18501 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offset' of undefined at WebGLSpriteRenderer.render (three.js:18501) at WebGLRenderer.render (three.js:22287) at render (canvas_particles_waves.html:184) at animate (canvas_particles_waves.html:157)`

Any ideas?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I got it working!

The CanvasRenderer demo draws its circles using 2D Canvas drawing commands, like so:

`var material = new THREE.SpriteCanvasMaterial( {
    color: 0xffffff,
    program: function ( context ) {

        context.beginPath();
        context.arc( 0, 0, 0.5, 0, PI2, true );
        context.fill();
    }
});`

2D drawing commands like that don't translate to 3D WebGL, so I replaced this with:

`var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 5, 32, 32 );
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0xffff00} );`

And directly below that in the nested for loop, the first line becomes:

`particle = particles[ i ++ ] = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );`

That's it! Everything else works as is.

Comment: `THREE.SphereGeometry( 5, 32, 32 )` is ~2000 triangles -- each! `THREE.SphereGeometry( 5, 4, 4 )` is more reasonable for this use case. You really should be using `THREE.Points`.

Comment: Definitely, thanks! Yes the code above is just copy paste from the three.js docs on SphereGeometry. I'll take a look at Points

Comment: By the way, here’s the particle wave canvas demo working in WebGL:
http://plu.sx/v2/

Code is here:
http://github.com/plus-x/plu.sx/blob/master/v2/js/setup-webgl.js ..... I'll implement your suggestion next

Comment: Type `renderer.info` into the console: 6,000+ draw calls; 300,000+ triangles. Try with `BufferGeometry` and `THREE.Points`.